# AppEngine service name and version in the GAE flexible env from my code at runtime in Java/Jetty?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, app-engine-flexible

How do I get the AppEngine service name and version in the GAE flexible env from my Java code at runtime in the Java 8/Jetty runtime?

I need the service and version to populate the ServiceContext info in the stackdriver error reporting on GCP.  https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the Stackdriver Error Reporting product manager.

To answer your question:
While I cannot find a clear documentation page for it. It seems that the environment variables `GAE_MODULE_NAME` and `GAE_MODULE_VERSION` contain the data you are looking for.

However, we recently changed how errors are processed on App Engine flexible environment: service name and version are now extracted automatically are not needed in the log entry payload. The `serviceContext` field is now optional on GAE Flex.

The [formatting error messages](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages) page should be updated in the following days to reflect this change.

Comment: I see the page was updated yesterday, but I don't know what the changes were (one of my biggest complaints with google).   The first paragraph says "It should be logged as a multi-line textPayload or in the message field of structPayload."  but it doesn't link to anything that explains this.  Logged where? What is textPayload and structPayload?

Comment: This setup page should contain the answer you are looking for: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/app-engine-flexible-environment

Comment: That is where I started.  If I am already doing cloud logging with appropriate severity mapping via this approach ([See my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39779646/2789445)).  Then do I even need to do this [*err*.json](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages) approach in order to get StackDriver Error Reporting?  I currently implemented both because I thought I had to do the latter in order to get StackDriver Error Reporting, and now I am concerned that StackDriver will pick up both and I will get duplicate errors.

Answer (score 1):

According to the current documentation the environment variables `GAE_SERVICE` and `GAE_VERSION` should be used.

It is also possible to get the instance ID with the `GAE_INSTANCE` environment variable.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating#modules