# Stackdriver - All logs are mapped as INFO

Tags: spring-boot, logging, kubernetes, logback, stackdriver

All my logs ERROR/WARNIN are mapped as INFO at Stackdriver.
I'm using logback and Im running my application in a Kubernetes cluster.

How can I setup my logback to Stackdriver?

Tks

Comment: I think this other post could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164730/gke-stackdriver-java-logback-logging-format

Comment: Thanks  AlbertoVI ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stackdriver logging agent configuration for Kubernetes defaults to INFO for any logs written to the container's stdout and ERROR for logs written to stderr. If you want finer-grained control over severity, you can configure Spring to log as single-line JSON (e.g., via `JsonLayout`<sup>1</sup>) and let the logging agent pick up the severity from the JSON object (see https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#process-payload).

<sup>1</sup>By default, `JsonLayout` will use "level" for the log level, while the Stackdriver logging agent [recognizes](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#special-fields) "severity", so you may have to override `addCustomDataToJsonMap`.

See also [GKE & Stackdriver: Java logback logging format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164730/gke-stackdriver-java-logback-logging-format)