# GCP and Spring logback. Severity is always info

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, logback, stackdriver, spring-cloud-gcp

When logging errors to stackdriver, every message is logged as INFO, even when using log.error or log.warn, etc., but the payload is correct.

[image]

I'd like to be able to filter by severity and get email on error.

I'm using Spring Boot and Logback. The app has been deployed on a Kubernetes Cluster on GCP.

Here is my logback-spring.xml

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/logging/logback-appender.xml" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss, UTC} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <springProfile name="prod,qa">

        <root level="WARN">
            <appender-ref ref="STACKDRIVER" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

And here is the dep added in Maven

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Spring Boot version: 2.1.3.RELEASE
Spring Cloud version: Greenwich.RELEASE

What is wrong with this config? Is there any other solution?

**EDIT: Just realized that the STACKDRIVER appender above is not the one logging to Stackdriver, but STDOUT is enough (maybe bc it's a Kubernetes cluster?), but the issue persists**

Comment: Do you need logback for logging separately? You can keep that in application.yml as you are using spring boot.
Check this one https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-slf4j-logging-example/

Answer (score 3):

The Stackdriver logging agent configuration for Kubernetes defaults to INFO for any logs written to the container's stdout and ERROR for logs written to stderr. If you want finer-grained control over severity, you can configure Spring to log as single-line JSON (e.g., via `JsonLayout`<sup>1</sup>) and let the logging agent pick up the severity from the JSON object (see https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#process-payload).

<sup>1</sup>By default, `JsonLayout` will use "level" for the log level, while the Stackdriver logging agent [recognizes](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#special-fields) "severity", so you may have to override `addCustomDataToJsonMap`.

See also [GKE & Stackdriver: Java logback logging format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164730/gke-stackdriver-java-logback-logging-format)

Comment: I extended JsonLayout and have overridden addCustomDataToJsonMap, adding "severity" to the map, then changed the xml using that layout for ConsoleAppender, but even though I can see it locally, I can't see it in StackDriver

Comment: That other SO answer did it though :)

Answer (score 1):

Directly using google cloud logging logback appender takes the severity from the log level on each case:

In Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-logging-logback</artifactId>
    <version>0.116.0-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

In logback.xml:

```
<appender name="Cloud" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>INFO</level>
            </filter>
            <log>YOUR_LOG_NAME</log>
            <resourceType>container</resourceType>
            <flushLevel>INFO</flushLevel>
</appender>

...
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="Cloud"/>
    </logger>
```

It is not the spring cloud component but solves the problem.

Comment: Most basic configuration: <appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender"/>

        <root level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="CLOUD"/>
        </root>