# Spring boot stackdriver logging is textPayload and not jsonPayload

Tags: spring-boot, logging, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I have a log filter that logs out essential request information for debugging and log analytics. But as you can see, the text payload is really hard to read.

I don't want to have to copy + paste this text payload into a text editor every single time. Is there a way to make stack driver print this in a collapsable json instead?

[image: image of text payload in stackdriver]

More info:
- GKE pod

```
@Component
class LogFilter : WebFilter {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogFilter::class.java)

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        return chain
                .filter(exchange)
                .doAfterTerminate {
                    val request = exchange.request
                    val path = request.uri.path
                    val routesToExclude = listOf("actuator")
                    var isExcludedRoute = false

                    for (r in routesToExclude) { if (path.contains(r)) { isExcludedRoute = true; break; } }

                    if (!isExcludedRoute) {
                        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                        val statusCode = exchange.response.statusCode?.value()
                        val requestTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
                        val msg = "Served $path as $statusCode in $requestTime msec"
                        val requestPrintMap = mutableMapOf<Any, Any>()
                        requestPrintMap["method"] = if (request.method != null) {
                            request.method.toString()
                        } else "UNKNOWN"
                        requestPrintMap["path"] = path.toString()
                        requestPrintMap["query_params"] = request.queryParams
                        requestPrintMap["headers"] = request.headers

                        requestPrintMap["status_code"] = statusCode.toString()
                        requestPrintMap["request_time"] = requestTime
                        requestPrintMap["msg"] = msg

                        logger.info(JSONObject(requestPrintMap).toString())
                    }
                }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is [customize Fluentd in GKE](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/customizing-stackdriver-logs-fluentd). Pretty much it's creating a Fluend daemonset for logging instead of the default logging method.

Once that is done, you can setup [structured logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging) to send [jsonPayload logs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/legacy-stackdriver/logging) to Stackdriver Logging.

Answer (score 0):

The default Stackdriver logging agent configuration for Kubernetes will detect single-line JSON and convert it to `jsonPayload`. You can configure Spring to log as single-line JSON (e.g., via `JsonLayout`<sup>1</sup>) and let the logging agent pick up the JSON object (see https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#process-payload).

<sup>1</sup>Some of the JSON field names are different (e.g., `JsonLayout` uses "level" for the log level, while the Stackdriver logging agent [recognizes](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#special-fields) "severity"), so you may have to override `addCustomDataToJsonMap` to fully control the resulting log entries.

See also [GKE & Stackdriver: Java logback logging format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164730/gke-stackdriver-java-logback-logging-format)