# GCP Log explorer shows wrong severity level of log records

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, logback, google-cloud-logging

I am running a java application in GKE and monitoring logs in Log explorer. Java application is writing logs to `stdout` and as far as I understand GKE agent parse it and send it to log explorer. What I found is that the log explorer shows `WARN` and `ERROR` messages with severity `INFO`.
I figured out that I can't change the default parser of logs and configured logback to represent java logs in JSON format suitable for GCP (I used implementation from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44168383/6718334)), here is an example:

```
{"message":"2022-02-17 12:42:05.000 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-8] DEBUG some debug message","timestamp":{"seconds":1645101725,"nanos":0},"thread":"QuartzScheduler_Worker-8","severity":"DEBUG"}
{"message":"2022-02-17 12:42:05.008 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-8] INFO some info message","timestamp":{"seconds":1645101725,"nanos":8000000},"thread":"QuartzScheduler_Worker-8","severity":"INFO"}
{"message":"2022-02-17 12:42:05.009 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-8] ERROR some error message","timestamp":{"seconds":1645101725,"nanos":9000000},"thread":"QuartzScheduler_Worker-8","severity":"ERROR"}
```

But it didn't help at all.

Please point me out where I am wrong with JSON format or maybe I need to configure something additionally on the GCP side. I've checked the official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging) regarding log JSON format and I don't understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation [link 1](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/managing-logs#best_practices) & [link 2](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging#special-payload-fields)

> Severities: By default, logs written to the standard output are on the INFO level and logs written to the standard error are on the ERROR level. Structured logs can include a severity field, which defines the log's severity.

> If you're using Google Kubernetes Engine or the App Engine flexible environment, you can write structured logs as JSON objects serialized on a single line to stdout or stderr. The Logging agent then sends the structured logs to Cloud Logging as the jsonPayload of the LogEntry structure.

---

If the manual implementation is not working, you may try to:

- Directly send logs to [Cloud Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/write)
- Use [this](https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging-logback) official Java logback lib (note: it's currently a WiP)