# GCP Logs Explorer parse textPayload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging

I have a service which generates logs in the below format

```
2022-07-25T06:31:52.909705Z, DEBUG, foo.fooApplication, using localDB path /config/LocalDB
2022-07-25T06:31:52.966801Z, DEBUG, localdb.LocalDBFactory, initializing password.foo.util.localdb.XodusLocalDB localDBProvider instance
```

GCP Logs explorer reads this as below

```
[
  {
    "textPayload": "2022-07-25T05:38:41.012837Z, DEBUG, foo.fooApplication, using localDB path /config/LocalDB",
    "timestamp": "2022-07-25T05:38:41.013044676Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2022-07-25T05:38:46.103891084Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "2022-07-25T05:38:41.018544Z, DEBUG, localdb.LocalDBFactory, initializing password.foo.util.localdb.XodusLocalDB localDBProvider instance",
    "timestamp": "2022-07-25T05:38:41.018744665Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2022-07-25T05:38:46.103891084Z"
  }
]
```

textPayload has severity as `DEBUG` and GCP marks it as `ERROR`. Is there a way to parse severity from textPayload?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCP Log explorer shows wrong severity level of log records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71158475/gcp-log-explorer-shows-wrong-severity-level-of-log-records)

Comment: @AtefHares, no this doesn't answer, in that use case the data is already present in a JSON format. My use case is to convert/parse CSV to JSON

Comment: @mayankb You can select various Levels of severity(Critical,Emergency)in logs explorer, Check whether the severity option is error type in logs explorer you can change that to debug for the logs that you have generated and you can convert that to CSV or Json format.

Please find this [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface?hl=en_US&_ga=2.111912333.-820331028.1626766507) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

`textPayload=~DEBUG` will find logs where "DEBUG" exists in the textPayload