# "Non zero exit: 1" error when using runtime: java-compat

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to change runtime of my application to enable log level filtering in Stackdriver( see: [How do I map my java app logging events to corresponding cloud logging event levels in GCP Felexible non-compat App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420400/how-do-i-map-my-java-app-logging-events-to-corresponding-cloud-logging-event-lev))

In app.yaml, when I change runtime to `java-compat`, I receive following error:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: Building and pushing image for service [default]
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your application does not satisfy all of the requirements for a runtime of type [java-compat].  Please correct the errors and try again.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.321 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-01T11:20:27+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/407M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy (default-cli) on project bookshelf-5: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy (default-cli) on project bookshelf-5: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.NonZeroExceptionExitListener.onExit(NonZeroExceptionExitListener.java:30)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.syncRun(DefaultProcessRunner.java:211)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.run(DefaultProcessRunner.java:137)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk.runGcloudCommand(CloudSdk.java:193)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk.runAppCommandInWorkingDirectory(CloudSdk.java:136)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.deploy(CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.java:90)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        ... 20 more
```

Following is my app.yaml file:

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: java-compat
env:    flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored

# [START env_variables]
env_variables:    # Logging options
  JAVA_OPTS: >-
    -D.level=INFO
# [END env_variables]
# [END runtime]

runtime_config:   # Optional
  jdk: openjdk8
  server: jetty9
```

The error log does not indicate what exactly is missing.

How should I update the application so that it is compatible with java-compat runtime.

Comment: Hi, I am working on figuring this one out today... as I am having the same exact problem. Just to confirm, you were not able to figure this out yet, correct?

Comment: One other note from the Google documentation: The Java 7 / Jetty 9 compat runtime (java-compat) and the Java 8 / Jetty 9 compat runtime (jetty9-compat) runtimes were deprecated on November 15th, 2016, and are not supported in the flexible environment.

Comment: I couldn't figure this out. Actually my primary problem is stackdriver cannot filter logs based on log level.

Comment: Do you have other Maven plugins defined in the pom? Try removing them, and rely fully on the appengine-maven-plugin. We were able to get through this error by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error message.
In my case, I found my Application was disabled in App Engine Config menu.
I was able to fix the problem by just clicking enable button.

Answer (score 0):

The "java-compat" runtime for App Engine Flexible [has been deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/upgrading#runtime_deprecations) and may no longer be used.

If you are trying to migrate from the Standard environment to the Flexible environment you can read about the difference in available services [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating).

To make your app.yaml compatible with the Flexible environment, be sure to use the configuration outlined in [Configuring your App with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml).