# Stackdriver does not show proper level for the logs written using slf4j with log4j2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-trace

I have a web application deployed on GAE. I am using log4j2 implementation of SLF4j for logging purpose.

I can see all my logs on stackdriver console. **But the level for all my logs is shown as info under stackdriver. It's not categorized properly based on the loglevel like debug, info, warning and error.**

e.g. my **log.error("error")** is also displayed **under info level** in stackdriver console.

*But when I use JUL implementation of SLF4 (slf4j-jdk14). All the logs are reported correctly with proper log level in stackdriver.*

> Can any one suggest what could be the issue?

Here is POM.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I have captured the screenshot of log4j2 and logback implementation where level is not shown correctly

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Please check ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420400/how-do-i-map-my-java-app-logging-events-to-corresponding-cloud-logging-event-lev#39779646

Comment: you can follow the below steps
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
     <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter"> level>WARN</level></filter> 
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.yogesh.log.GCPCloudLoggingJSONLayout">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} %M - %msg%n</pattern>
            </layout></encoder>  </appender>
And then create the GCPCloudLoggingJSONLayout as given in the above link