# How get GCP Error Reporting from Java App running on GKE ( google kubernetes engine )

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-error-reporting

in case of Java App Engine, if exception occur from Java App, i can get GCP Error reporting automatically like [this](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/quickstart)

But in case of Java App on GKE, i can't get GCP Error Reporting

How does it can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/java) Stackdriver Error Reporting is automatically enabled for App Engine environment applications. However on GKE, you must add the cloud-platform access scope when creating the cluster.  The preferred  way to collect the error is to  able to post to Stackdriver Error Reporting using the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/report) or [Error Reporting Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/reference/libraries)

Answer (score 2):

you should install [Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/installing) to GKE; while one can also use it together with [Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/prometheus). theses features are currently still in beta stage (not being covered by any SLA). also see the [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org) data collector, which is rather relevant to the `Logging API`. this [visual diagram](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/customizing) might explain the most reliable who reports to whom:

[image: K8 Architecture]

this one [SLF4J example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420400/how-do-i-map-my-java-app-logging-events-to-corresponding-cloud-logging-event-lev/39779646#39779646) shows how log from within a Java environment, there there's relevant documentation for [Logging Application Events with Java](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/logging-application-events#understanding_the_code) (what you might be actually looking for). in principle, the logger within the Java environment needs to tell the local agent, what is going on.

concerning the `Logging API` in Kubernetes, see [Logging Using Stackdriver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver/) and [Customizing Stackdriver Logs for Kubernetes Engine with Fluentd](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/customizing-stackdriver-logs-fluentd); there is more than one way to do that.

the `Monitoring API` and the `Logging API` can be used independently, while they nevertheless observe the same resources and the same timeline, that's why utilizing both makes sense.

concerning the access scope required:

> You must be an Owner of the project containing your cluster.