# logs disappear in cloud run once I start using google's LoggingAppender in logback?

Tags: logback, google-cloud-run

I have no idea how to debug since there is no errors.  I have this logback file but this made all the logs disappear for my cloudrun instance EXCEPT the system.out stuff that logback logs on startup..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" debug="true">

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
        <!-- Optional : filter logs at or above a level -->
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <flushLevel>WARN</flushLevel> <!-- Optional : default ERROR -->
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC-SERVERLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
    </appender>

    <!-- TBD for later use for apps that use log4jdbc it doesn't hurt apps that
        don't use it -->
    <logger name="jdbc.sqlonly" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="jdbc.audit" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="jdbc.resultset" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="jdbc.connection" level="WARN" />

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-SERVERLOG" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas why logging stops working or where the logging is going to?  Now that I changed logging to this, logging seems to go to the void :(.

I also tried out this post which logs to ConsoleAppender but NOTHING shows up in the json format although it is doing a line for EACH log statement I do which is really nice

[GKE & Stackdriver: Java logback logging format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164730/gke-stackdriver-java-logback-logging-format/44168383#44168383)

I then tried this approach which is using FileAppender

[How do I map my java app logging events to corresponding cloud logging event levels in GCP Felexible non-compat App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420400/how-do-i-map-my-java-app-logging-events-to-corresponding-cloud-logging-event-lev/39779646#39779646)

My logback for this one was

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/var/log/app.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="com.orderlyhealth.GCPCloudLoggingJSONLayout">
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg</pattern>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC-SERVERLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</appender>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Java logging instructions in the documentation should help: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#run_manual_logging-java

In Cloud Run, output to Stdout and Stderr are forwarded on to Stackdriver. Logs which are recorded in files are lost.

I'm not sure the implications of the ASYNC-SERVERLOG appender, but on Cloud Run there is only CPU available to process and send logs while a request is being processed, so if something is asynchronously sending logs it will only work during that request or a future request that reaches the same container instance.